# How to show the correct frame with python and pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm a beginner in python , and I try to generate the frame with pyQt.
Here is my code , and I have some trouble that can not show a correct frame .

At first I wrote , and it can showed the result that I want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.resize(250, 150)
widget.setWindowTitle('simple2')
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I changed the wording of object-oriented later , and it can't show a frame which I except.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Apple(QtGui.QWidget):
    def _int_(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('simple2')

if __name__ == "__main__":         
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywidget = Apple()
    mywidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Someone knows how do I fix my error ?

Comment: You do not indicate what is not really working. Is there a stacktrace? What do you expect, what does really happen?

Comment: What is a "correct frame" for you? I can run your code and it shows an empty window, which is expected from the code.

Comment: The code is really can run .
However it can't show the correct size and title which I set up.
If you can , I want to improve it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you deets , stellasia and mdurant .
I re-edited the question above, I definitely say that I want to show .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a typo in your code

```
def _int_(self,parent=None):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit your code this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -* coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Apple(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def _init_(self): # if you have no parent you don't need to write parent = None. And yes, there was a typo
        super(Apple, self).__init__()  # it's a little bit better than super().__init__()
        #self.widget = QtGui.QWidget() # you've already init QWidget. This code do nothing 


if __name__ == "__main__":         
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywidget = Apple()
    mywidget.setWindowTitle('simple2') # here must be window title
    mywidget.resize(250, 150)          # and resizing
    mywidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now you get what you want